# How do I get the clientCert.Subject.CommonName from a golang tcp handshake?

Tags: go, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have a bunch of clients connecting to my TLS tcp endpoint with different certs. I'm trying to use `RequireAndVerifyClientCert`:

```
    certPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    clientCACert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("client-ca.crt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    certPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(clientCACert)

    // Create a base TLS config
    baseTLSConfig := &tls.Config{
        ClientCAs:    certPool,
        ClientAuth:   tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert,
    }
```

So I can get access to `ConnectionState().PeerCertificates[0]` and read the `clientCert.Subject.CommonName` first BEFORE I tell it which server cert and key to use. i.e. each CommonName cert needs a different server side cert and key. It's not just one server cert and key for all the connections.

```
listener, err := tls.Listen("tcp", ":8080", baseTLSConfig)

    for {
        conn, _ := listener.Accept()
        clientCert := conn.(*tls.Conn).ConnectionState().PeerCertificates[0]
        switch clientCert.Subject.CommonName {
```

But either this cast fails: `(*tls.Conn)` and I can't call `ConnectionState` or I make another tcp.Server call but then `len(PeerCertificates)` is zero. I've tried:

`GetConfigForClient: func(hello *tls.ClientHelloInfo) (*tls.Config, error) {`

passing that in vs. `tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert` or in addition to but the *tls.ClientHelloInfo doesn't have the info I need.

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re trying to do, but you probably want to use one of the `Get*` or `Verify*` function fields in the [`*tls.Config`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Config) rather than trying to intercept the data on your own.

Comment: how can I make it more clear? I want to setup a normal TLS server but I don't know which server.cert and which server.key file to use until after the client connects and presents its cert which tells me the right server.cert and server.key files to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I can get access to ConnectionState().PeerCertificates[0] and read the clientCert.Subject.CommonName first BEFORE I tell it which server cert and key to use.

It is impossible to decide which server certificate to use based on the client certificate.

In the TLS handshake the server first sends its server certificate, then requests the client certificate and only after this the client will sends its client certificate to the server.

Comment: thank you. So, how does something like aws iot core work with each "thing" making a secure MQTT connection with an individual cert to an endpoint like tcps://foo.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883 how does that server know which server cert to use? It could be any of 1000's of things connecting?

Comment: @AndrewArrow: based on the description in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/server-authentication.html I would suggest that the certificate is per domain name of the server. Nothing suggests that the select it by client certificate.

Comment: i see my confusion. I was thinking the client send it's "device_id" inside it's custom cert. But really it just connects like a normal https connection (yes it has unique certs) and if there is man-in-middle the https will fail like normal. But I also do `VerifyPeerCertificate: func(rawCerts [][]byte, verifiedChains [][]*x509.Certificate) error` to make sure the device_id and cert match.